# Binder Error: CondaEnvException: Pip failed (pip subprocess error)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip, mybinder

I'm trying create binder for my repo, here's the link to my repo: https://github.com/UCB-stat-159-s23/project-group14.git
But binder is failing and giving me these errors:

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: file:///home/jovyan/project_tools (from -r /home/jovyan/condaenv.7epkswi7.requirements.txt (line 1)) does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Please help!

I'm thinking it's an environment problem/

Comment: It seems to be building and launching fine now. And the three notebooks in the root directory all run without error in the resulting session. I see this was posted 
7 hours ago, yet you made changes to your repo 6 hours ago. Please, if you fix things, update your post so that it doesn't waste time of those who thought could help you.